# After upgrading to OS Mavericks on iMac it stopped recognizing my ethernet cable

Tags: macos, mac, internet, ethernet, osx-mavericks

After I finished upgrading my Lion OS to Mavericks OS, it stopped recognizing my Ethernet cable, therefore I can't connect via Ethernet to the Internet but only via Wifi.

On the Networks preferences it's simply red and won't change.

None of these have helped:

- restart my router
- restart my mac
- changed the cable
- creating new location
- deleting the Ethernet instance and creating a new one

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after updating to Mountain Lion. This is what I did to fix it:

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Network**.
2. Delete all Ethernet services from the service list.
3. Create a new Ethernet service.
4. Set **Configure IPv4** to **Manually**.
5. Enter the IP address that the router would assign to your computer through DCHP, and the subnet mask and router IP into the relevant boxes.

   [image]
6. Click **Apply**.

Comment: I have tried every combination but still it says Not connected and doesn't change it's color